# Photo Competition 2022-04-25: Star Trail

Tags: photo-competition

### Theme: Star Trail

A long exposure shot of a beautiful star trail.

This theme was suggested by [Soham](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/44923/).

#### Voting Rules

- View the submissions [sorted by active](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/129205/photo-competition-2022-04-25-star-trail?answertab=active#tab-top) to give every submitter a fair chance
- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on May 9, 2022 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include:**

   - a **title** for the photo
   - a **location and date**, if known
   - **camera, lens, film stock, and exposure settings**, if known
   - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

Suggest a theme by writing a new answer at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread. Please make sure to check the [PotW theme ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first, to make sure you aren't recycling a theme.

The highest-voted theme will be the next theme.

Good luck!

**Previous contest**: [2022-04-11: Claustrophobic](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/129081/)
**Next contest**: [2022-06-06: Reflections](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/129502/)

Comment: scottbb - Please check the attribution below the photo of the week, the photo was originally posted by Aganju.

Comment: @user24582 Thanks for the heads up. [Fixed](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7243/11924) =)

Comment: No submissions? That's unusual!

Comment: @spikey_richie yeah. I think it happened once before.

Comment: I live in a built-up area, with no reasonably close dark zones to move to, so astro is pretty much out for me.

Comment: @scottbb so do we close this competition down, and start the next one? Or extend the date on this one out by a few weeks?

Comment: I think it might be time to call this one a lost cause and move on to the next theme

Comment: Would hate to see it die, but I realize there is very little participation... sad.

Comment: @spikey_richie sorry for letting this one die on the vine. I think part of the problem might have been that the "Submit your photo" link in the sidebar didn't point to this question, it still pointed to the previous one. (My fault)

Comment: I started recycling themes for the next contest, starting with "Reflections". It got a lot of submissions originally. I'm pretty much following @MichaelC's suggestion there. Also looking for suggestions on new ways to get some theme suggestions and reuse some "evergreen" themes.